# Multiplying column values

Tags: mysql, math

In mysql, if one has a numeric (integer, decimal, or float) column, he can add all the values using the `sum` function:

> ```
> select sum(mycolumn) from mytable where condition;
> ```

Suppose I'm interested in the *product* of the values in the column. For example, given

> ```
> +----------+
> | mycolumn |
> +----------+
> |        1 |
> |        2 |
> |        1 |
> |        3 |
> +----------+
> ```

, I'd want `select fcn(mycolumn) from mytable` to return `6` (for some function `fcn`). How should I do this? Please bear in mind that there may be many rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for zeroes as well as positive & negative numbers:

```
select 
case 
when sum(case when mycolumn = 0 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 then 0 
else
 case when mod(sum(case when mycolumn < 0 then 1 else 0 end),2) = 0 then 1 
 else -1 
 end * exp(sum(log(coalesce(mycolumn,1)))) 
end as product
from mytable
where condition;
```

This is pretty ugly-looking so it might be worth bunging the whole lot into a [user defined function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-function-udf.html) to prevent having to dig out the query every time.

Comment: +1, nice. (And I should have thought of that.) Also won't work for zeroes. For zeroes, you can check first whether any value is zero. For negatives, you can multiply the result in this answer by the number of negative values mod 2, which should be doable; or maybe there's a better way. Edit the answer to make it more complete and you get the checkmark (unless and until someone posts an even better solution).

Comment: ask and ye shall receive ;-)

Comment: And `exp(sum(log(coalesce(mycolumn,1))))` should be `exp(sum(log(abs(coalesce(mycolumn,1)))))`. (I've suggested this edit, but it has two 'reject' votes so far and thus looks like it won't go through.)